# new factor-level assignment behaves weirdly depending on the position of the new factor string in the list

Tags: r, categorical-data

I know that adding new levels to an object of class `factor` is pretty straightforward. However, when I put the factor level to-be-added in the first position in the list, the actual values in the object (vector) change.

Here is what I am talking about:

```
test <- factor(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "b"))

test
#[1] a a a b c a c b
#Levels: a b c

levels(test)
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

## Works OK
levels(test) <- c(levels(test), "d")
#[1] a a a b c a c b
#Levels: a b c d

levels(test) <- c("d", levels(test))

## The values have changed
test
#[1] d d d a b d b a
#Levels: d a b c
```

I'm just curious why the position of the new factor level in a list affects the factor levels and the factor itself are modified.

Comment: First of all, `c()` doesn't create a list, but a vector. A list in R is created with `list()`.

That said, the order is important in context. For example, if you're going to plot using your factor in `facet_grid(~factor)` inside ggplot, for example, the factors are separated in the order that you specified.

Comment: Got it! So the order does matter! Seems like in my example above, a <- d, b <-a, c <- b. Fascinating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *levels* of a factor are the character strings associated with an underlying integer-valued variable (an *enumeration*).

If we examine the underlying structure of this variable:

```
test <- factor(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "b"))
```

we see:

```
str(test)
## Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 2 3 1 3 2
```

What `levels()` does is to assign codes to the integer values *in order*: `levels(test) <- c("d","a","b","c")` makes the correspondence 1 <-> "d", 2 <-> "a", 3<-> "b", 4 <-> "c". Thus the values that have an underlying value of 1 (the first through third and sixth elements of the vector) now have associated label "d".

A safer way to add a new level would be:

```
test <- factor(test,levels=c("d","a","b","c"))
test
## [1] a a a b c a c b
## Levels: d a b c
str(test)
## Factor w/ 4 levels "d","a","b","c": 2 2 2 3 4 2 4 3
```

This changes the *order* of the levels (which matters for plotting and parameterizing statistical models), but it uses the character values when assigning integer values ...

Comment: Explains it all. Thank you!